# .env variables not visible inside settings.py file of a Django project run with Docker

Tags: django, docker

I am playing with Docker (deliberately not using docker-compose for now).
The problem is that my variable set in .env file is not visible to settings.py, resulting in `None` being rendered by `print(os.environ.get('TEST_VAR'))` in `settings.py`.
The problem goes away if I define the `TEST_VAR` variable inside the Dockerfile.
Anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Here's how my Django project looks like:

Project layout:

```
my_project
   my_project
       settings.py
       .env
   manage.py
   requirements.txt
   Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8


RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
    libaio1 \
    git \
    wget \
    curl \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    software-properties-common \
    zip \
    && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*


RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

.env

```
TEST_VAR='wow'
```

The commands I run:

```
docker build -t simple-project .
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 simple-project
```

Note that .env is on the same level as settings.py, however I have tried to move it one level up where, say, manage.py is located.

Comment: How did you set the `.env` ? Just putting file not expose variables in it.

Comment: Em...I am a newbie in things like deployment, Docker, etc...Could you please clarify a bit more on that ?

Comment: Is it best to use django-environ ? https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend you `django-environ`, check documentation at https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

once installed via `pip install django-environ`, create `.env` file in the root of your project:

in `/.env`

```
SECRET_KEY="#b)oj5(wpt!1f1e8+%1sa4gcp*4b5#k^w=15gg80=_=3oavf3w"
DEBUG=on
```

and then in `settings.py`, you can use your predefined environment variables like

```
import os

# django-environ
# https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
import environ

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Load and read .env file
# OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
env = environ.Env()
env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = env.bool('DEBUG', False)

[..]
```

Answer (score 1):

Compose will [automatically load environment variables from a `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/), but that's a Compose feature.  Plain `docker run` and other ways of launching containers won't do this automatically.

`docker run` has an equivalent [`--env-file`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) option that you need to explicitly set:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 \
  --env-file my_project/.env \
  simple-project
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's say your `.env` file which is located at the base directory, looks like this:

```
# Database
HOST=my_sql_server
DB=my_db
```

And then you want to make these your image's environment variables, in Dockerfile, include this `RUN`:

```
RUN export $(grep -v '^#' .env | xargs)
```

What it does is to take those lines that don't start with `#` (because those are comments), then set the environment variables.

From your dockerfile, I haven't seen the step where you tell Docker to take `.env` file and set the environment, that's probably what you're missing.

Comment: `RUN export ...` is a no-op: any variables you set this way will get lost at the end of the `RUN` line.  You can't dynamically set environment variables in a Dockerfile like this.

Comment: and that's the point David, your docker file should not contain your secrets. Use `export` to set the secrets during some certain processes that need them, for example, `collectstatic` or `migrate`. At the end of the Dockerfile, `RUN rm .env` to make sure we remove `.env` file from Dockerfile too. The secrets then should be uploaded to the host separately. Again, do not store your secrets (esp your personal passwords) in the image (that can be access by many others in your team).